# Command line tools to monitor POST/GET requests of a loaded website

Tags: curl, wget

When I load a website with Firefox and open up the Network Profiler, I can see all the POST and GET requests the site is making.

[image]

I would like this functionality from the command line. Does any one know of a command line tool which I could use to request the page with say Firefox HTTP headers, and then monitor all outgoing network requests from this page?

Comment: I am not aware of a command line tool for this, but i know a proxy server between you and the internet can log this...but it would be an overkill...

Comment: I am just thinking about tshark

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?:

```
tcpdump -nli eth0 -w - 'tcp port 80' | tshark -i - -R'http.request.method == "GET"'

tcpdump -nli eth0 -w - 'tcp port 80' | tshark -i - -R'http.request.method == "POST"'
```